# how to implement multiple segues using dynamic cells in Xcode?

Tags: ios, objective-c, xcode

i have a table view with dynamic prototype cells divided into 2 different sections named "Forums" and "Threads". When i click on a tableview cell from the Forums section, i want to transit to the same page with a different data to display while if i click a cell from the Threads section, it should open a different scene. In short, two different types of transition segues from 2 different tableview sections)

Can anyone please help me with this?

Comment: can you explain it little bit more i am confuse.

Comment: Your question is not easy to follow, but I think you are asking how to implement two different segues for two different UITableViewCells?  Is this correct?  More importantly, what you have tried?

Comment: well, yes...... i am trying to have two segues from cells in two different sections.... one segue transits to the same view while the other to a different view.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

1. Make sure the table view controller is embedded in a navigation controller.
2. Hook up two push segues to the table view controller (not to the cells).
3. Give those segues appropriate identifiers in the storyboard using the attributes inspector tab on each segue.
4. In `-tableView didSelectRowAtIndexPath:` add an `if` statement to detect which section the row tapped was in.
5. In the branches of the `if` statement, call `-performSegueWithIdentifier` on your controller using the identifier of the appropriate segue .
6. If you need to set up anything in the view controller you're seguing to from the table view, override `prepareForSegue: sender:` in the table view controller.

Answer (score 0):

Very helpful, it worked for me, but I had to used **BOTH didSelectRowAtIndexPath AND prepareForSegue**, while I was reading in other posts that this is not very good.

I read that we need to use only the prepareForSegue if we need to set up any stuff...

Do you think that I should continue with both of them?

Thanks!